# In list comprehension, I used the condition in place of expression. .Spot me error why it is not printing answer in numbers instead of boolean

Tags: python, list-comprehension

My code(Gives ans in boolean form)

```
list=[x%3==0 for x in range(1,50)]
print(list)
```

Another code(Gives ans in numeric form)

```
list=[x for x in range(1,50) if x%3==0]
print(list)
```

Comment: cause x is a number

Comment: x%3 == 0 evaluates to a boolean, x is a number.  a) builds of list of that b) builds a list of numbers that evaluates to true using x%3 == 0.

Comment: Because the very first expression inside a list comprehension is what’s getting put into the list…

Comment: What error? Both versions are correct, and do something different, and are supposed to do something different. I don't understand what you expect to happen, or why.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that you write in the list while doing list comprehension gets into your list. In the first case you write `x%3==0` in the start which can only return boolean values, in the second you write `x` in the start which is an integer.